# Light weight Linux to go on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox

I am looking for non gui based linux that I can set it up as guest os using Virtual box on Windows 7. Any ideas?

Comment: I just need the terminal to setup apache mysql php etc

Comment: Why non-GUI?  You can easily run X inside the Windows 7 virtual box.  I have a full install of Ubuntu on mine

Comment: Is Linux really necessary for that? There is a package called XAMPP located here that will install all of those tools on a Windows machine: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Answer (score 6):

I myself am running **[Arch Linux](http://archlinux.org/)**. It's intended to be as lightweight as possible.

You may like **[coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/)** - it is not a distribution, but rather a special type of a VM - the Linux kernel isn't fully virtualized, so it's a little faster, especially if you don't need an X server. (It's still possible to use Xming or Cygwin/X though.)

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with the Debian netinstaller, and tell it to install a minimal system.  Then apt-get install the pieces you need.

Answer (score 5):

[Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatIsubuntu/serveredition) is probably a really easy to go (though I haven't tried it in Virtual Box).  You can  have it automatically install LAMP for you during the install process.

Answer (score 2):

There are a *TON* of choices. I say go with what you're most familiar. I'll throw out [CentOS](http://www.centos.com) as that's what I'm installing on a headless server as I type this.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth your time to check out [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). It will allow you to run many Posix-compliant packages natively from Windows.

Comment: +1 for Cygwin.  Cygwin is going to be leaner than a hosted VM, it's easy to install, and it's functionally just as good for non-GUI software.  Note that there are native Windows versions of Apache, PHP, etc too.

Answer (score 1):

Another good server distribution is [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/).  It's similar to Red Hat Enterprise Linux and is a good place for people starting out with Linux.

But if all you want is a web server stack, there are Windows versions of the entire Apache, MySQL, and PHP (LAMP) stack.  Try Googling for XAMPP or WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Portable Ubuntu for awhile:
http://portableubuntu.demonccc.com.ar/

Seems to work pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of distributions that start without a GUI will contain only the bare basis needed to be able to install everything you want. If you would want my opinion then check out [Gentoo Linux](http://www.gentoo.org/):

> Gentoo Linux, a special
>   flavor of Linux that can be
>   automatically optimized and customized
>   for just about any application or
>   need. Extreme performance,
>   configurability and a top-notch user
>   and developer community are all
>   hallmarks of the Gentoo experience.